# How to generate 8 digit unique number using MOD10 algorithms

Tags: java, gosu, guidewire

I have a requirement to generate a unique 8 digit number with one check digit using Luhn algorithm in Java. The number should be unique every time we call the function.

Comment: The question which you are pointing is to validate the number, but my requirement is to generate the 8 digit number using Luhn algorithm.

Comment: There was a link to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/ModulusCheckDigit.html]

Comment: The link is not working...

Comment: Sorry, looks like I appended a `]` on the end my mistake

Comment: @user1166528: you only need to generate a unique 7 digit number, then use Luhn algorithm to create the 8th check digit

Comment: The Luhn algorithm in gosu is available as github gist here https://gist.github.com/l-ray/a6ecbf2f3b496634ee83